# Kqlmagic returns No valid xcolumn

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kqlmagic

The following example query works in the Azure Data Explorer UI but not with Kqlmagic in Jupyter Notebook.

```
%%kql
let min_t = toscalar(demo_make_series1 | summarize min(TimeStamp));
let max_t = toscalar(demo_make_series1 | summarize max(TimeStamp));
demo_make_series1
| make-series num=count() default=0 on TimeStamp in range(min_t, max_t, 1h) by OsVer
| render timechart
```

It just throws `No valid xcolumn`. Any idea whats the issue?

Note: The database demo_make_series1 is available on the help cluster from ADX.

Comment: Please try an explicit use of **render** and share the results: `| render timechart with (xcolumn=TimeStamp, ycolumns=num, series=OsVer)`

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz with your suggestion it throws `No valid ycolumns`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This indeed looks like a bug in KqlMagic rendering. We shall check and update. Meanwhile you can use mv-expand before rendering. Regardless, in make-series I suggest you avoid using the deprecated range(...) syntax in favor of 'from ... to ... step ...'. Here is the updated query:

```
%%kql
let min_t = toscalar(demo_make_series1 | summarize min(TimeStamp));
let max_t = toscalar(demo_make_series1 | summarize max(TimeStamp));
demo_make_series1
| make-series num=count() default=0 on TimeStamp from min_t to max_t step 1h by OsVer
| mv-expand num to typeof(long), TimeStamp to typeof(datetime)
| render timechart
```

thanks,
Adi

Comment: thanks! this seemed to work, but i still didnt got the image graph appearing on Jupyter Notebook. I tried with Safari and Chrome, seems to be a different issue though.